# trasfer vectors between python and c++ packages

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi;
I want to subscribe a vector from a node written in python to a node written in c++.
I use the std::msg float64multiarray type in the two nodes, however, the message is not received
Can you help me please
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263147/trasfer-vectors-between-python-and-c++-packages/) by [ismaisma](https://answers.ros.org/users/30631/ismaisma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-04**:
Not an answer, but: if by 'vector' you really mean a standard `xyz` triplet, please try to use `geometry_msgs/Vector3` as its semantics are much clearer.

**Comment by [ismaisma](https://answers.ros.org/users/30631/ismaisma/) on 2017-06-04**:
the vector is the coordinates of a manipulator and the position with the orientation of a mobile robot, and an instantaneous velocity of the wheels of the mobile system

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-04**:
Then I would suggest you use a combination of `Pose` and `JointState`, or an `Odometry` msg. The whole point of ROS is to use as much semantically correct messages as possible. A multi-array throws away any and all meaning the original data might have.

**Comment by [ismaisma](https://answers.ros.org/users/30631/ismaisma/) on 2017-06-04**:
I'm new in ROS, how could I combine Pose and JointState msg !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To pass messages between nodes they need to have the same topic name, the same topic type, and the nodes need to be connected to the same ROS master.

If you're running both nodes on the same computer, they're probably connected to the same ROS master. I wouldn't worry about this unless you're trying to run ROS across multiple machines.

In your code you should be able to see that you're using the same topic name and message type (although the message type syntax is slightly different in python and C++).

When both of your nodes are running, you can use `rosnode info` with the node name to see which topics your node is actually publishing and subscribing, and if your nodes are connected you'll be able to see the connection between nodes.

You can also use `rostopic list` to see the list of topics, and `rostopic echo` to confirm that your publisher is actually publishing messages.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0